# How can I call a masked function in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, masking

Let's say I have this C++ code:

```
void exampleFunction () { // #1
    cout << "The function I want to call." << endl;
}

class ExampleParent { // I have no control over this class
public:
    void exampleFunction () { // #2
        cout << "The function I do NOT want to call." << endl;
    }
    // other stuff
};

class ExampleChild : public ExampleParent {
public:
    void myFunction () {
        exampleFunction(); // how to get #1?
    }
};
```

I have to inherit from the `Parent` class in order to customize some functionality in a framework. However, the `Parent` class is masking the global `exampleFunction` that I want to call. Is there any way I can call it from `myFunction`?

(I actually have this problem with calling the `time` function in the `<ctime>` library if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do the following:

```
::exampleFunction()
```

`::` will access the global namespace.

If you `#include <ctime>`, you should be able to access it in the namespace `std`:

```
std::time(0);
```

To avoid these problems, place everything in namespaces, and avoid global `using namespace` directives.

Comment: or `::std::time(0)` of course, to access the std version without any ambiguity